# DataJpaTest loads all classes from my context and starts the application like a normal run

Tags: spring-test, data-jpa-test

DataJpaTest loads all classes from my context and starts the application like a normal run
How do i prevent him from loading the entire context and only the repositories ?

I also see this in my logs
15:45:04.406 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils -- Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [be.smals.employerregistry.employerregistry_event_generator.atce.entity.RepoTest]: RepoTest does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
15:45:04.807 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper -- Found @SpringBootConfiguration be.smals.employerregistry.employerregistry_event_generator.EmployerRegistryEventGenerator for test class be.smals.employerregistry.employerregistry_event_generator.atce.entity.RepoTest